# How to align child widgets of wrap widget to left?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I use a wrap for listing some widgets I have some problems. Wrap automatically align-center its child widgets. How can I align-left if there is one widget on the row?

Wrappping Output - 1

[image]

Wrapping Output - 2

[image]

```
Wrap(
              crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
              alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
              children: customAnnouncementLabels
                  .map(
                    (customAnnouncementLabel) => LabelChip(
                      text: customAnnouncementLabel.name,
                      color: customAnnouncementLabel.bgColor,
                      isDetailed: false,
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
```

Comment: By default, the wrap layout is horizontal and both the children and the runs are aligned to the start which is aligned left..maybe your parent widgets makes it aligned center..kindly checked

Comment: Thank you so much, I aligned parent widget and problem is solved :)

Answer (score 7):

Try wrapping your Wrap Widget with a SizedBox Widget with maximum width

```
SizedBox( 
     width: double.infinity, 
     child: Wrap( 
              children: []     // Your Children           
))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try it :
>
> ```
> runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` for left align,  `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` for right side can be used with Column to get similar output.

Comment: Wrap widget does not have these properties

Comment: Yes, it is meant to be used with Column not Wrap as an alternative way - the output will be similar